# Scalar Multiplication in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to perform simple scalar multiplication in R, but I'm running into a bit of an issue.

In linear algebra I would do the following:

[image: scalar multiplication]

Here's how I've implemented this in R:

```
A <- matrix(1:4, 2, byrow = TRUE)
c <- matrix(rep(3, 4), 2)
A * c
```

This produces the correct output, but creating the scalar matrix *c* will be cumbersome when it comes to larger matrices.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Perfect and simple. If you submit this as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: R does scalar multiplication by default. It is actually (very strangely) harder to do matrix multiplication in R. For that you need a special operator such as `%*%`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thanks for the heads up on the operator. Would I be correct in saying that `*` will do multiplication by element and `%*%` will do proper matrix multiplication?

Comment: @ChuckD. Yes, Exactly

Comment: Why did you put a bounty on this?

Comment: @DavidArenburg There's an option to add a bounty to reward an answer you find particularly useful (I left a comment to that effect above in the bounty section). The answer by Hans has been really useful to me throughout a linear algebra course, so I want to thank him for his time with the reputation bonus. I also really appreciate the comment you left about matrix multiplication. Overall, I'm really enjoying the R community here on this site and I want to give back when I've been helped by someone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `R` the default is scalar. For matrix multiplication use `%*%`. `t` is transpose and `solve` will give you the inverse. Here are some examples:

```
a = matrix(1:4,2,2)
3 * a
c(1:2) %*% a
c(1:2) %*% t(a)
solve(a)
```

Here is a link: [matrix algebra in R](https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html)

Comment: Thanks for including `t` and `solve`, I'll get some use out of those as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use the function `drop()` to convert a 1x1 variable matrix into a "real" scalar. So you can write `drop(c)*A` and you don't need to replace `c` with the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

A=c(1,2,3,4)
A
m=matrix(A,nrow=2,ncol=2)
m
c=3
m*c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).